# bootstrap input field and dropdown button submit

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

GOAL: To have a input box where a value can be typed, then to the right of that input box is a bootstrap dropdown button where they can select "Store Name, City, State or Zip".

They would type in name (say Walmart) and then select Store Name. When they select Store Name it would submit the form and send two post values to be handled by php:

search term | search type

Here is the code I have for the button:

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="POST" />
      <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>Search Store Names</li>
            <li>Search City</li>
            <li>Search State</li>
            <li>Search Zip Code</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="POST" />
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" name="search_term" type="text">
    <input class="span2" id="search_type" name="search_type" type="hidden">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li onclick="$('#search_type').val('store'); $('#searchForm').submit()">Search Store Names</li>
        <li onclick="$('#search_type').val('city'); $('#searchForm').submit()">Search City</li>
        <li onclick="$('#search_type').val('state'); $('#searchForm').submit()">Search State</li>
        <li onclick="$('#search_type').val('zip'); $('#searchForm').submit()">Search Zip Code</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

`$_POST['search_term']` will be the entered text and `$_POST['search_type']` will be one of `store`, `city`, `state`, or `zip`.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution. Thanks so much.  Weird how Bootstrap uses input / dropdown submit buttons, but finding a solution to capture the value is so difficult. Thanks Michael.  Oh, also... for me at least, I lost the hover-over effect with this solution (vs. hyperlinking the list elements.  I added this to my implementation.  Otherwise, did exactly as you wrote.  Big thx.

Answer (score 6):

For a pure html and css solution, try this:

```
<li>
  <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-link" name="submit" value="Search State">
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown input {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 26px;
}

.dropdown .btn-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

Comment: change `.dropdown` to `dropdown-menu` to affect that class too. nice solution thanks loads