# Sumbit multiple dropbox fields to $_POST in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I see from [this previous question´s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770777/submit-selection-from-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-to-post) answer that you can send a dropbox value to $_POST with this jquery but now i have to do it with 2 dropbox elements.

In my case both $_POST variables are mixing up and having the value of the 'category' dropbox but i need that each $_POST variable come with its corresponding dropbox value.

This is the html for both dropbox fields:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label"  for="provider_name">Nombre del Proveedor</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <!-- ----------Dropdown---------- -->
                <div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
                    <button type="button" name="provider_name" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span data-bind="label">Elige una</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" id="provider_name" name="provider_name" />
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
                        <?php
                        foreach($array_providers as $row ){
                            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row["nombre_proveedor"].'</a></li>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label"  for="category">Categoría</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <!-- ----------Dropdown---------- -->
                <div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
                    <button type="button" name="category" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span data-bind="label">Elige una</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" id="category" name="category" />
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
                        <?php
                        foreach($array_categories as $row ){
                            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row["nombre_categoria"].'</a></li>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This is the jquery im using:

```
    $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event )
{
    var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

    $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
        .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
        .end()
        .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

    return false;

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function()
    {
        $('#provider_name').val($(this).html());
        $('#category').val($(this).html());
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is requirement to include each `li` element `html` as `#my-topic` value ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Only the one that is selected in each dropbox

Comment: Is `js` at Question not returning expected results ?

Comment: My apologies, i didn´t test the code before asking the question, testing now...

Comment: Ok i tested with 2 dropbox elements and both $_POST variables come with the same value repeated. The question is updated to better reflect the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to differentiate between the two drop-downs by adding an if condition in the jquery asking to identify the parent of the list by an id i set earlier on the html.

Here i add both dropdowns html code and the jquery for reference:

First Dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="provider_button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Elige una <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <input id="provider_name" type="hidden"  name="provider_name"/>
    <ul id="provider_list" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <?php
        foreach($array_providers as $row ){
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row["nombre_proveedor"].'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Second dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="category_button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Elige una <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <input id="category" type="hidden"  name="category"/>
    <ul id="category_list" class="dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <?php
        foreach($array_categories as $row ){
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row["nombre_categoria"].'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(event)
    {
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);

        if($(this).parent().attr("id") == "provider_list"){
            $('#provider_button').text($target.text()); //this is to change the button when option selected
            $('#provider_name').val($(this).text());
        }
        if($(this).parent().attr("id") == "category_list"){
            $('#category_button').text($target.text()); //this is to change the button when option selected
            $('#category').val($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

The drop-down toggle behavior is handled by bootstrap.
I  don't know if this is the best solution but i am a newbie and this is what worked in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make thing clarified, from the question you have provided, they don't actually do anything fancy with the jQuery code. What they have done is: When you click on the "li" tag, it will pass the data to the hidden input and then force the form to start submitting process.

If you are planning to do the same things but with multiple dropdown, the most simplest way is to use .parent().

```
$("li").parent() // this will return you the <ul> object containing the li
```

Look at my jsfiddle for more info:

http://jsfiddle.net/mankinchi/dfbhL81s/

In my jsFiddle, I have 2 different dropdown and input (I didn't hide the input just for clarification. And didn't put it in the form or force it to submit). As you can see, I distinguish the drop down menu by id and input by class. When you click on a "li" tag,

```
var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

this will get the id of the "ul" tag contains it and use it to find the "input" tag

Comment: Thanks, i will test this tomorrow as my mind is starting to fail at this late hour.

Comment: Okay :). Just comment here if something not going as intended and I can update my answer :)

Comment: I found a solution and posted the answer, thanks for your answer it made me understand about parent elements :)